# Counts the Vowels in an input

Tags: python-3.4

Instead of showing how many vowels appear in ends up counting them. How can I fix the issue?

```
def main():  
    sentence=input("Please type a sentence")  
    countA=0     
    for i in sentence:    
        if i =="a":  
            countA+=1    
            print("The letter a appears:", countA,"times")    
    countE=0           
    for i in sentence:  
        if i == "e":  
            countE+=1  
            print("The letter e appears:", countE,"times")  
    countI=0  
    for i in sentence:  
        if i == "i":  
            countI+=1  
            print("The letter i appears:", countI,"times")  
    countO=0  
    for i in sentence:    
        if i == "o":  
            countO+=1  
            print("The letter o appears:", countO,"times")  
    countU=0  
    for i in sentence:  
        if i == "u":  
            countU+=1  
            print("The letter u appears:", countU,"times")  
    countY=0  
    for i in sentence:  
        if i == "y":  
            countY+=1  
            print("The letter y appears:", countY,"times")  


main()
```

Comment: Sir, Please format the code in your question AS CODE, you can do this by selecting the block of text that is code, and clicking the "code" icon on the editing bar (when editing your question)

Comment: Use the `count` method of `str`: `sentence.count(letter)`.

Comment: "[...] in ends up counting them. How can I fix the issue?": you need to dedent your `print` statements to be outside each of their for loops.

Answer (score 0):

`Sentence.count()` would be way much easier, but I fixed that for you. Take print commands out of the for loops.

```
sentence=input("Please type a sentence")
countE=0           
for i in sentence:  
    if i == "e" or i == "E":  
        countE+=1  
print("The letter e appears:", countE,"times")  
countI=0  
for i in sentence:  
    if i == "i" or i == "I":  
        countI+=1  
print("The letter i appears:", countI,"times")  
countO=0  
for i in sentence:    
    if i == "o" or i == "O":  
        countO+=1  
print("The letter o appears:", countO,"times")  
countU=0  
for i in sentence:  
    if i == "u" or i == "U":  
        countU+=1  
print("The letter u appears:", countU,"times")  
countY=0  
#Or use sentence.count(letter)
#for i in sentence:  
 #   if i == "y" or i == "Y":  
  #      countY+=1  
sentence.lower()
print("The letter y appears:", sentence.count("y"),"times")
```